# Listview - Footer at the bottom of screen

Tags: android, listview, layout, footer

I have a ListView with a footer added with `listview.addFooterView(footerView);`

All works as expected excepted in one case: when my listview's items doesn't fill the whole screen, I would like the footer to be at the bottom of the screen, instead of being in the middle. Is there a way to do this easily? Or should I change my layout?

Thanks

EDIT: that might help (this is what I want)
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you may want to make the footer view a separate view anchored to the bottom of the screen, rather than as a child of `ListView`. By doing that, however, the footer view will no longer be scrolling off-screen when there are lots of items in the `ListView`. In stead, it will always be visible at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah, I already did it but that is not what I'm expecting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it to always be at the bottom of the screen, no matter how long your `ListView` is, then get rid of `listview.addFooterView(footerView);` and use a `RelativeLayout. Give your`ListView` the property

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and give the property to your footer

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then please be a little more specific about what you want and provide a picture of what you want if possible.

**Edit**

After reading the comments this might work. There might be an easier way but you could do something like

```
     listView.post(new Runnable()
     {       
         public void run()
        {
            int numItemsVisible = listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - 
            listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if (itemsAdapter.getCount() - 1 > numItemsVisible)
            {   
                 // set your footer on the ListView
            }
            else
            {
                 footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
         }
```

`footerView` would be a custom `layout` that you would create with the properties I referenced above. This should set that to `visible` if the items aren't more than can fit on the screen. If they are more than can fit then you apply the footer view on the `ListView` as you are now. This might not be the best way but its the first thing that comes to mind. You would run this code just before you set the `Adapter`.

Comment: You only want the footer visible if the `ListView` doesn't take up the whole screen?

Comment: I want it to be at the bottom of the screen if the listview doesn't fill the whole screen. If it fill the whole screen, I want the footer to act as a normal listview footer (scrollable).

Comment: Thanks for your edit, very interesting, but something cannot be handled: the number of visible items depends on the screen size.

Comment: Yes, and this should give you the number of visible items after it is drawn

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ListView footer as footer for the whole layout.
You're better off with RelativeLayout as root element for your layout, and then a direct child of it containing the footer view with the attribute:
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @codeMagic response, you could add a listener to check when your adapter gets updated and then update the footer

```
registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                updateSmartFooter();
            }
        });
```

where updateSmartFooter is the function he described

```
 private void updateSmartFooter {
     listView.post(new Runnable()
     {       
         public void run()
        {
            int numItemsVisible = listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - 
            listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if (itemsAdapter.getCount() - 1 > numItemsVisible)
            {   
                 // set your footer on the ListView
            }
            else
            {
                 footerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spent a lot of time to research, I found the best solution for it.
Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890559/6166660
and https://github.com/JohnKuper/recyclerview-sticky-footer

For details:

- Create a **StickyFooterItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration** like the example code below.
- After that, set ItemDecoration to your recyclerView:

**`recyclerListView.addItemDecoration(new StickyFooterItemDecoration());`**

**---------------------------------------**

```
 public class StickyFooterItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final int OFF_SCREEN_OFFSET = 5000;

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, final View view, final RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int adapterItemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        if (isFooter(parent, view, adapterItemCount)) {
            if (view.getHeight() == 0 && state.didStructureChange()) {
                hideFooterAndUpdate(outRect, view, parent);
            } else {
                outRect.set(0, calculateTopOffset(parent, view, adapterItemCount), 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideFooterAndUpdate(Rect outRect, final View footerView, final RecyclerView parent) {
        outRect.set(0, OFF_SCREEN_OFFSET, 0, 0);
        footerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                parent.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private int calculateTopOffset(RecyclerView parent, View footerView, int itemCount) {
        int topOffset = parent.getHeight() - visibleChildsHeightWithFooter(parent, footerView, itemCount);
        return topOffset < 0 ? 0 : topOffset;
    }

    private int visibleChildsHeightWithFooter(RecyclerView parent, View footerView, int itemCount) {
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int onScreenItemCount = Math.min(parent.getChildCount(), itemCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < onScreenItemCount - 1; i++) {
            totalHeight += parent.getChildAt(i).getHeight();
        }
        return totalHeight + footerView.getHeight();
    }

    private boolean isFooter(RecyclerView parent, View view, int itemCount) {
        return parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == itemCount - 1;
    }
}
```