# how to display footer view to the end of the screen in the case when the list has very few items?

Tags: android, listview, footer

I want to add a footer to the listview. When the number of list items are more,the footer works fine.
But when listview has very few items,the footer gets displayed in the middle of the screen,just below the listview .which looks shabby.In such case i want the footer to align parent bottom. 
Thankyou in anticipation.

Comment: Basically you want your footer to be at the bottom of the screen even if there is only 1 item AND you want it to stay at the very end (even offscreen) if there are many items?

Comment: yes,this is exactly what i want.

Comment: There are many similar posts but no satisfactory answer.cant get the reason to down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a simplest example of what you want. you can customize it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/footer" >

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want do that you said in comment you must set layout param's of footer in code, you must get the size of your list, then get the number of row that shows in screen, then

```
 if (listSize < numRow)
     //set footer to bottom of your list
 else
     //  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: this will display the footer below the listview which will be displayed all the time.and not after all the list items are scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your listview's height is set to wrap_content?

As far as I know the footer is added at the bottom of the listview. If you set the listview's height to match_parent it should be aligned to the bottom and also the footer should be displayed there.
(If you use a relative layout simply set listview's attribute alignParentBottom="true" in your .xml file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView with RecyclerView.ItemDecoration to implement this behavior.

```
public class StickyFooterItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

/**
 * Top offset to completely hide footer from the screen and therefore avoid noticeable blink during changing position of the footer.
 */
private static final int OFF_SCREEN_OFFSET = 5000;

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, final View view, final RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int adapterItemCount = parent.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    if (isFooter(parent, view, adapterItemCount)) {
        //For the first time, each view doesn't contain any parameters related to its size,
        //hence we can't calculate the appropriate offset.
        //In this case, set a big top offset and notify adapter to update footer one more time.
        //Also, we shouldn't do it if footer became visible after scrolling.
        if (view.getHeight() == 0 && state.didStructureChange()) {
            hideFooterAndUpdate(outRect, view, parent);
        } else {
            outRect.set(0, calculateTopOffset(parent, view, adapterItemCount), 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

private void hideFooterAndUpdate(Rect outRect, final View footerView, final RecyclerView parent) {
    outRect.set(0, OFF_SCREEN_OFFSET, 0, 0);
    footerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            parent.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private int calculateTopOffset(RecyclerView parent, View footerView, int itemCount) {
    int topOffset = parent.getHeight() - visibleChildsHeightWithFooter(parent, footerView, itemCount);
    return topOffset < 0 ? 0 : topOffset;
}

private int visibleChildsHeightWithFooter(RecyclerView parent, View footerView, int itemCount) {
    int totalHeight = 0;
    //In the case of dynamic content when adding or removing are possible itemCount from the adapter is reliable,
    //but when the screen can fit fewer items than in adapter, getChildCount() from RecyclerView should be used.
    int onScreenItemCount = Math.min(parent.getChildCount(), itemCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < onScreenItemCount - 1; i++) {
        totalHeight += parent.getChildAt(i).getHeight();
    }
    return totalHeight + footerView.getHeight();
}

private boolean isFooter(RecyclerView parent, View view, int itemCount) {
    return parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == itemCount - 1;
}
```

}

Make sure to set **match_parent** for the RecyclerView height.

Please have a look at the sample application https://github.com/JohnKuper/recyclerview-sticky-footer and how it works http://sendvid.com/nbpj0806

A Huge drawback of this solution is it works correctly only after notifyDataSetChanged() throughout an application(not inside decoration). With more specific notifications it won't work properly and to support them, it requires a way more logic. Also, you can get insights from the library **recyclerview-stickyheaders** by **eowise** and improve this solution.