# How to execute code after Activity creation in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to execute some code immediately after the form is shown.

I want to check the size of a button on the form and use the same size to create a new button at runtime.

I tried onStart() and onResumed(), but they do not work.

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: I think you are not looking for when the activity is created, but the layout is built. I have not dealt with that, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418868/how-to-know-when-an-activity-finishes-a-layout-pass) seems a good place to start.

Comment: You can post a `Runnable` on it. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283686/listview-footer-at-the-bottom-of-screen/18283819#18283819)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a globallayout listener. Add the listener at onActivityCreated.
Check this example:

```
button1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                       button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        button1.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                   //here the size is already available. create new button2 here with the size of button1
                }
            });
```

Comment: I will try this later today.

Comment: Just want to make sure this: would above code run only once?  I can manage even if it runs multiple times.  Thanks

Comment: If you remove the listener the code will only run once. Notice the first 4 lines used to remove the listener.

Comment: Oh, I got it.  It was obvious but I missed it.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at the onCreate() method, that is the function that will run when your app is first loaded in to memory

Comment: The layout information such as size won't be available yet

Comment: The layout will be avalable after you call the setContentView(R.layout.<layout>)

Comment: @mpop There will be access to the `Views` but no guarantee that they have been completely measured so the size, most likely, won't be available yet just because you call `setContentView()`